# Why can I declare a javascript var multiple times?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, var

Why am I able to declare a var multiple times? I would expect an error.

This code raises an error:

```
let a = true;
let a = false;
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared

Why doesn't this raise an error too?

```
var b = true;
var b = false;
```

Expected: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'b' has already been declared

Comment: Related: [Declaring a Javascript variable twice in same scope - Is it an issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726948)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because there's variable hoisting with `var`, but not with `let` (or `const` for that matter).

So that means that each time you use `var`, it'll essentially cancel out the previous operations because to the JavaScript interpreter, your first code looks like:

```
var b;
b = true;
b = false;
```

But this doesn't work with `let` or `const` because `let` and `const` are block scoped, whereas `var` is function scoped.

Answer (score 2):

`var` gets hoisted; duplicate variable names are ignored. To the interpreter, your second snippet looks like:

```
var b;
b = true;
b = false;
```

In contrast, `let` is *not* hoisted, so duplicate declarations are forbidden.

Comment: *"let is not hoisted*" isn't correct. All declarations (`var`, `let`, `const`, `function`, `function*`, `class`) are hoisted in javascript https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222689/3082296